# python optparse get specified number of args after an option

Tags: python

```
./hello_world -c arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Is it possible to code so that option -c would only get two arguments (arg1 and arg2)?

```
parser.add_option("-c",
                  action="append2",        <--- maybe something like that?
                  dest="verbose",
                  help="make lots of noise [default]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the nargs attribute.

For example:

```
parser.add_option("-c", nargs=2, dest="verbose", help="make lots of noise [default]")
```